# Initialised 'useState' hook with boolean prop, but state is undefined - React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

so i'm sending an object sippet with the field 'followed' as a prop to a component with this code (simplified):

```
export const SippetDisplayHeader = ({ sippet, toastAuthor = null }) => {

  const [followed, setFollowed] = useState(sippet.followed)
  console.log(followed)
  console.log(sippet.followed)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setFollowed(sippet.followed)
  }, [sippet.followed])

  return (...
  )
}
```

now, i made sure its there before its being passed to this component, and sippet.followed logs correctly, but still the followed state logs and initialises to undefined. why? sippet.followed is boolean, and in this case true.

i tried solving this with a useEffect as you can see and it works but kinda messes up the initial styling of the component.

the parent component's return (said component is sippetDisplayHeader, 5th line):

```
return (
   sippet ?
    <article className='p-2 flex flex-col border-t border-t-black bg-transparent'>
      <section className='w-full flex flex-col'>
        <SippetDisplayHeader i={i} sippet={sippet} toastAuthor={sippet.is == 'toast' && sippet.ref_sippet.author} />
        <article onWheel={handleWheel} className={`container flex w-full justify-center flex-col items-center p-1 bg-neutral800 ${sippet.is == 'toast' ? 'border-t-2 border-l-2 border-neutral-800 hover:shadow shadow-black duration-300' : ''}`}>
          {code.blocks && code.blocks.map((block, i) => (
            block.type === 'text' ?
            <TextareaAutosize
              key={i}
              readOnly={true}
              value={block.value}
              className='w-full resize-none caret-white bg-transparent whitespace-pre-wrap overflow-hidden active:outline-none focus:outline-none px-1 text-xl'
            />
            :
            <div key={i} onWheel={handleWheel}
            className='flex overflow-x-scroll w-full text-sm custom-scrollbar'>
            <CodeMirror
              value={block.value}
              readOnly={true}
              theme={tokyoNight}
              extensions={[langs.get(code.lang)]}
            />
          </div>
          ))}
          </article>
        <SippetDisplayFooter sippet={sippet} />
      </section>
    </article>
    :
    <SippetSkeleton />
  )
```

Comment: Have you tried nullish-coalescence: `useState(sippet.followed ?? false)`? Also, what is a "sippet"?

Comment: Your ternary statement doesn't make much sense - you're setting `followed` to the same value regardless of the condition.

Comment: if followed depends on sippet.followed, theres no need to create a state, just use the sippet prop directly.

If sippet prop changes from the parent, the change will be updated on the child

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl
it results in false, but sippet.followed is true, so that's exactly my question, why does it result in undefined? i guess there's maybe some kind of delay in loading the object? but it does not sound right

also sippet = super intelligent pixy puppet eating tofu
or a bad idea of a word play for code snippets.

about the ternary - 
i know, it's not there to stay, and that's not the issue anyway

Comment: @LeeSkies I didn't know if it was a typo. Anyways, I would make sure if `sippet` is loaded before setting any real state. Maybe you can flag the object until it's ready to use?

Comment: @SaulMontilla i didn't include the whole component but yes, the state is supposed to change inside this component internally, unrelated to the parent

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl whats flagging? if you mean conditional rendering, i did check the sippet object in the parent component's return statement, isnt that supposed to do the same?

Comment: @LeeSkies if followed state will be controlled by SippetDisplayHeader, but its first value will be determined by sippet prop, keep the code as you have it but remove the useEffect.
If parent change, SippetDisplayHeader wont be affected, they will be independent

Comment: @SaulMontilla i added the useEffect after it initially didn't work without it, but ik it's just a workaround and i'm still trying to find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear your understanding of what is actually happening. `useState` actually persists the state variable across re-renders, thus, unless `setState` is explicitly called, changing the value of the prop does not change the state.

Secondly, why you are doing `setFollowed(followed == sippet.followed ? sippet.followed : sippet.followed)` ?

You can simply write

```
useEffect(() => {
    setFollowed(sippet.followed); 
    // in case you want to make sure it is boolean
    // setFollowed(!!sippet.followed);
  }, [sippet.followed])
```

Comment: yeah ik, but the initialisation isn't happening correctly. the weird useEffect is coz i tested some options and forgot to change it back, sry :| i'll update it now in the question